# How to create a reactive binding with variable taking a tuple as parameter

Tags: ios, swift, binding, reactive-programming, reactive

I am trying to create a binding for my variable looking as so

```
var reactiveVariable: (((Bool, Profile)) -> Void)?
```

However ton connect the binding I don't get it I don't understand how to connect take a tuple and a parameter and extract the data from it.
I tried something like this:

```
VC?.reactiveVariable = { [weak self] (boolean, profile) in
      self?.boolean = boolean 
      self?profile = profile 
 }
```

Thanks for help I don't understand where my tuple went

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VC?.reactiveVariable = { [weak self] result in
          self?.boolean = result.0 
          self?profile = result.1
   }
```

When you bind with something, it doesn't matter if the object is a tuple or simple object, the object always come as a single entity